# How to keep a moving div inside another div (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

I have a very peculiar problem:
I have a moving `div` inside a container (also a `div`). And I want to assure that that element stays within it. I made a `controller` object which contains my utility functions and in fact, my code works for the **bottom and right** borders. However, the element easily leaves through the **top and left** borders.

Here's the `controller.js` file. I hope that's enough.

```
//A controller to store all the utility functions
var Controller = { 

    //Function that returns true if the element is outside the container
    elementIsInContainer : function(element) {
        //get the container
        var container = document.getElementById(element.parentId);

        //convert style to int
        var elementTop = parseInt(element.style.top);
        var elementLeft = parseInt(element.style.left);

        //Checks all borders, returns an object containing a bool for each side
        //a value is true, if the element is outside
        return {
            //check right border
            right: (container.offsetWidth < elementLeft + element.offsetWidth),
            //check bottom border
            bottom: (container.offsetHeight < elementTop + element.offsetHeight),
            //check left border
            left: (elementLeft < 0),
            //check top border
            top: (elementTop < 0)
        };
    },

    //Returns an object containing two strings to assign to element style
     getElementPosition : function (element) {
         var result =  { 
                    left: (parseInt(element.style.left) + "px"),
                    top: (parseInt(element.style.top) + "px")
                };
         return result;
    },

    //checks if element outside container, if so, it resets
    keepElementInContainer : function(element) {
        //Note: can it be optimized?

        //Get result of comparison with borders
        var inContainerResult = this.elementIsInContainer(element);

        //Get the coordinates of the element
        var elementPosition = this.getElementPosition(element);

        //reset top
        element.style.top = inContainerResult.top ? "0px" : elementPosition.top;
        element.debug(element.style.top);
        //reset left
        element.style.left = inContainerResult.left ? "0px" : elementPosition.left;

        //reset right
        element.style.left = inContainerResult.right ? 
                              element.maxLeft : elementPosition.left;
        //reset bottom
        element.style.top = inContainerResult.bottom ? 
                             element.maxTop : elementPosition.top;
    },       
};
```

Comment: Create  sandbox demo that others can fork that replicates problem

Comment: I just tried to create the sandbox... But in it the moving div stays inside the container... O.o In my original project, the div moves upon 'devicemotion' events. In the sandbox I used simple keyboard event. Could this affect it in any way? I thought it had to do with my logic. Here's the [fiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lywmqso/)